# Where appears android:description label from your manifest?

Tags: android, manifest

android:label parameter is displayed just under your icon on the home screen, but I can't see where the android:description label is displayed on the phone (Home screen, Applications Settings menu,... ?).

I didn't find the answer in the Android official documentation.

Any idea?

Comment: I didn't understand your question : You can't visualize the "description" field while editing the manifest file ?

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it is more clear. I can't see the string attached to android:description parameter neither on the Home screen or in the settings.
So I don't know what is its purpose.

Comment: Is it possible that this is used to tag your application for searching in the Google Play store?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an excellent question, and I likewise can find no answer.

The value for android:description does not seem to appear in app selection screens (for generic intents). There is no option in the app tray to view more details about the application. It does not show in the App Manager. The Android Market description is set through the Android Market website when someone publishes an app and does not seem to come from the app itself.

I thought that, like android:title, it may show only in certain themes. However, none of the themes that I see in http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/values/styles.html or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html seem like they would include a description.

The only other possibility I can think of is that it was added "just in case" they wanted to use it in some app or version of Android later on... and that they never got around to it, making it useless for the time being. Unfortunately, we may never know, unless someone from the Android team itself talks.

Summary: as best as I can find, android:description does not show ANYWHERE.

Comment: Downvoting because of the answer by Fishy Joel. Since the AndroidManifest is like "a public API", other applications can access the value.

Answer (score 10):

Although it's not displayed anywhere I have seen by the Android OS, The application description can be obtained programmatically by using the following function

`CharSequence android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.loadDescription(PackageManager pm)`

There are some 3rd party applications available in the Market that make this call, and display information about other individual applications.

Comment: Do you a good way to call/read ALL of these tags and infos from the Manifest file? in a Activity.

Answer (score 5):

Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#desc)  for `android:description` states

> ... a user-readable text about the application, longer and more
>   descriptive than the application label. The value must be set as a
>   reference to a string resource. Unlike the label, it cannot be a raw
>   string. There is no default value.

This statement is very important if you carefully read it. Here's how I'd decipher it:

*"..longer and more descriptive..."* - Certainly, this means it's not meant for visual display. But rather, it suggests that it's to be used internally by an API.

*.."no default value"* - This suggests that each application will have a unique value

My best educated guess would be this tag acts as a `meta-tag` which could be used by Google internally to understand (?) what each app tries to do, or to give the Android Market engine more insight for better SEO experience.

In all cases, I'd **NEVER** leave that field blank just for the sake that it's not visible!

Comment: "no default value" does not guarantee that each application will have a **unique** value. There's nothing stopping me to put the same description in all my applications. Also, leaving the field blank is not a good suggestion. As stated by others, it can appear on some places.

Comment: I don't talk about leaving the field blank if you read my answer fully before down-voting it!

Comment: Very sorry about that, I missed the word "never". Could you perhaps edit and mark that word bold, then I can remove my downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> Applications -> Running services. If you don't have a description you'll see "This service was started by it's application..." If you do have a description, it replaces the aforementioned.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is used for accessibility concerns (like in HTML) by providing a textual explanation (more than a simple title) of what is displayed by the activity.

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/checklist.html (the doc is related to contentDescription attribute for UI components but it is probably the same purpose)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to use android:description in Application section for accessibility and so far no luck. The screen reader is not using it. Seems odd that Android added ContentDescript

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was wondering that too, but I thought of putting the description here anyways in case it's ever used - and it's being used haha.

My app is installed as a system app. When I installed the app as a system app and right after that, installed it as a normal app (so system app + updates), I could see nothing. On a test I was doing on Safe Mode, I uninstalled the updates and only remained the APK in the system folders (so a system app without updates). That's when the description showed up.

Note 1: I'm using here a Blackview BV9500 with Android 8.1 AOSP based. Could be just my case, but I'd say it's now (as I said, AOSP based).

It shows on the title on top of the app window (that top title bar the activities have), and also showed on the launcher - both places instead of android:label (which should be the one to be there). If I go to Settings and search for the app, it also shows the description. No longer the label. I'll just take that off here xD.

Note 2: Nova Launcher doesn't show the description though. It shows the label. But the phone's main launcher does show the description (find out now).

Anyone who doesn't install the app as a system app I think will be fine (no idea where it's used more though).

**EDIT:** Seems to have been just a bug... When I removed the description from the app, it started showing the app package name, and then android:name. Reinstalled it and doesn't do this anymore and I can have the description there. Never mind, I guess.