# Why android:description need for?

Tags: android, android-manifest

In Android manifest file there are android:description field. This is what provided by [Android guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html):

> android:description
>
> User-readable text about the application, longer and more descriptive
>   than the application label. The value must be set as a reference to a
>   string resource. Unlike the label, it cannot be a raw string. There is
>   no default value.

It is not mentioned the aim of this field.

Can or not user see this field? Where user can see it? Are there devices where user can see it?

Whether this field affect on position in Google Play search or in other markets (Kindle Fire, Nook, Samsung market, etc)??

What the purpose of this field? Should I fill it or can simple left it empty?

Comment: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420730/where-appears-androiddescription-label-from-your-manifest :)

Answer (score 1):

[According to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420730/where-appears-androiddescription-label-from-your-manifest) the best guess anyone came up with was if you wanted to obtain the description from the Manifest of other applications.  I guess if you were creating an app-manager application for example.  You would obtain the description of the app from that.  Other than that, it's not really used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This must be only for longer and more descriptive as stated in [docementation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#desc).

There is another interesting answer [Where appears android:description label from your manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9402654/432903) comparing it to `meta-tag`.